# c# Winform remove selected item from multiple listviews in form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My winform application has a listview for every day of the week. Each listview (listSun, listMon, listTue, etc) has a list of tasks for the day. I can remove the item by stating the list specifically, but I cant get it to work by selection.

I want the user to be able to click an item from any day and with a simple function determine what list is selected and remove the selected item.

The logic Im trying at the moment is Foreach listview in the form delete the selected item. here  is the code ive tried so far.

```
  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (ListView listview in this.Controls)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem listitem in listview.SelectedItems)
                    listitem.Remove();
            }
```

Of course this isn't working, but I am open to suggestions fix or take another route.

Comment: Are you sure all of ListView controls are element of the this.Controls? Maybe you have made ListView in the GroupBox or Panels.

Comment: The form has no Groupboxes or Panels, The listViews were drag and dropped from the toolbox via the designer.

Comment: You just want to remove selectedItems from listView, right?

Comment: yes. I just want to not have to repeat the foreach code for all 7 listviews (days). The exception is: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'.

Comment: Are you comparing ListViewItem with some label?

Comment: this.Controls has various controls not only ListView, bur Labels, and buttons too. foreach tried to Labels or Buttons to cast to ListView, so It threw Type Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

First, create property for the Form class.

```
private ListView selectedListView {get; set;}
```

When user selects some items one of the ListViews, set it to the property.

```
// ListView Clicked Event
var userSelected = (ListView)sender;
if(userSelected.SelectedItem != null)
    selectedListView = (ListView)sender;
```

and remove SelectedItem with selectedListView.Items.Remove().

Comment: It took me a second to wrap my head around your suggestion, but once I did it worked beautifully. It even cleaned up code i hadn't wrote but thought i was going to write.  ultimately done with
foreach (ListViewItem listitem in selectedListView.SelectedItems)
            {
                listitem.Remove();
            }
Thank you very much!

Comment: @eatumup that would have easily worked :p check my answer to see why it didn't! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is this :

```
   foreach (ListView listview in this.Controls)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem listitem in listview.SelectedItems)
                    listitem.Remove();
            }
```

Foreach loop internally casts the item of the collection to the left hand side variable type
(In this case its ListView).

So what happens is... you have different controls inside `this. Controls` like labels, groupbox etc...
When you try the foreach like that, and hit a label in that control collection, the foreach loop tries to cast the label to listview, and fails.

You could fix this with a bit of linq by replacing your `this.Controls` foreach with :

```
foreach (ListView listview in this.Controls.OfType<Control>().
Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(ListView)))
 {
      foreach (ListViewItem listitem in listview.SelectedItems)
      listitem.Remove();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that I am reading your comment I remember stumbling upon a similar thing with buttons in a groupbox like a year or two ago. I dont write too often... But ultimately I had to specify the TypeOf. I completely forgot about that part of the syntax. Thank you for reminding me

Comment: you're welcome!  just remember its to make your collection a collection of same type so you could iterate through without invalid cast exceptions.

Comment: Funny enough i ran into another instance where i needed to use this answer. But the syntax above isn't quite right. Where does not exist in this winforms case.  So for those who may see this post and reference it; here is the correct syntax:

foreach (ListView listview in this.Controls.TypeOf(ListView))
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem listitem in listview.SelectedItems)
                    listitem.Remove();
            }

Comment: well i read it again and i notice because i was writing the answer on phone and had no compiler to check for syntax errors, i had some issues there.also forgot to cast all of the controls to conntrol type by doing `this.Controls.OfType(Control).Where()` else you wont be able to do the where on the collection of controls, hence the error. bu tstill what you suggest still works, but what i suggested will let you iterate through more controls like  `GroupBox`, `Panel`,  and other containers as well.  i editted the answer and fixed the syntax errors there. my apologies.